# Informix JDBC PySpark Read Results in Column Names as Column Values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, informix

I'm reading data from various JDBC sources using PySpark's read method. JDBC reads from Teradata, mySQL, Oracle, SQL Server are all working 100%, however, I'm now trying to read from Informix and the result is the column headers in the ***column values*** in stead of the actual data:

```
query_cbu = '''
SELECT first 5 
ac2_analysis_p
FROM informix.ac2_aux_cust
        '''
```

*Specifying the header option did not help:*

```
df_cbu = \
      spark.read.format("jdbc") \
      .option("url", url) \
      .option("dbtable", '({}) tbl'.format(query_cbu)) \
      .option("user", db_username) \
      .option("password", db_password) \
      .option("header", "true") \
      .load()

df_cbu.show()
```

Result:

```
+--------------+
|ac2_analysis_p|
+--------------+
|ac2_analysis_p|
|ac2_analysis_p|
|ac2_analysis_p|
|ac2_analysis_p|
|ac2_analysis_p|
+--------------+
```

Using the same jdbc driver (ifxjdbc.jar) values are returned correctly from DBVisualiser:

[image]

I can't imagine any mechanism that can cause this. Can anyone advise me where to start looking for the problem?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't post pictures of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question to include the code and output in the body of the question. However based on your title, my guess is that you need to set the `header` option to `true` (it defaults to `false`).

Comment: @pault Thanks, I've tried to place the code but it results in a trick of escape characters etc to incorporate the inverted commas, also it's nice to show the context the user interface of Jupyternotebook and DbVisualizer provides. Unfortunately setting the header option to true did not make a difference. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe (and I saw this once before some time ago so going from memory here) that you need to enable DELIMIDENT in your JDBC driver URL.

`DELIMIDENT=Y`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_040.htm#ids_jdbc_040

The reason is that while the other JDBC drivers already quote username/table names in the metadata that Spark goes after, Informix JDBC does not which confuses Sparks JDBC layer. Enabling DELIMIDENT in the driver adds those. There are other repercussions to using DELIMIDENT so make sure it does what you want, but it should be fine to turn it on.